# MPMoviePlayerController Hides the full screen Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I am using MpMoviePlayerController in my app to stream the video. It works fine on iPhone but on iPad when i play the player in embedded view it shows the controls (like buttons for full screen and volume), on tapping the screen. But when i go to full screen by tapping on full screen button and then come back to the small view by tapping the button on upper right corner the controls hide mysteriously. Even on tapping the player's screen the controls do not come back.

I just want to know is there any way so that player retain its controls after coming back from full screen.?

Here is my code.

```
self.movieViewController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
self.movieViewController.moviePlayer.contentURL = contentURL;
self.movieViewController.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;


self.movieViewController.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=YES;
[self.movieViewController.moviePlayer setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill];
[self.movieViewController.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
```

Answer (score 0):

When the `MpMoviePlayerController` enters fullscreen mode, it's no longer attached to the view, but to a new window.

You can control the player after coming back from full screen with **`MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification`** like this:

In you `viewDidLoad`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didExitFullScreen:) name: MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:nil];
```

And

```
- (void) didExitFullScreen:(NSNotification *)notification
{
      // your code to handle player after exiting fullscreen
}
```